# Suggestion required for any lightweight Ubuntu OS supported with LattePanda SBC with touchscreen gesture support

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, touchscreen, sbc

I'm hoping to get some assistance with a touchscreen issue on a LattePanda board running Xubuntu20.04.6 LTS (XFCE4 environment). We have a Qt application designed for this setup, but we're encountering a problem:

Issue: The system doesn't fully support touchscreen gestures. The screen displays a cursor, making it appear like a mouse-controlled system. Goal: We want to disable the cursor and enable a full touchscreen experience with gestures for our application.

Constraints: We're working on a resource-limited Single-Board Computer (SBC).
Xubuntu (XFCE4) is preferred due to its lightweight nature. However, we're open to exploring alternatives if necessary.

Solution Required: If Xubuntu limitations prevent a full touch experience, we'd appreciate suggestions for a lightweight OS with a desktop environment that offers better native touchscreen support for SBCs.

Thanks

Comment: All Ubuntu are basially the same if it comes to support by the kernel for hardware (some dropped support for hardware a bit earlier than others but basically you can redo that bu adding modules/drivers). If one version does not work it is likely another does not either or you need to do some configuring to a device (where 1 OS does that for you and another does not).   have a read here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=222769  Mind that we are not a discussion forum: on AU you can ask about how to fix an issue with touchscreens. Suggestions for a DE/OS are always opinionated ;)

Comment: Set up touchegg for gestures https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg. You can try Raspberry Pi OS for a very lightweight desktop (https://downloads.raspberrypi.com/rpd_x86/images/rpd_x86-2022-07-04/2022-07-01-raspios-bullseye-i386.iso). Note that it is not Ubuntu, but it is based on Debian.

Comment: As it wasn't mentioned yet: Xubuntu is EOL since April 2023 - the flavors of Ubuntu only give 3 year LTS support, not 5 like Ubuntu. Thus, you may want to think about a different OS anyway. Lubuntu is lighter than Xubuntu. However, none of the *buntus is really "light" compared to some other distros and, as already mentioned, the core system is mostly the same for all *buntus, thus any hardware-related issue will be identical on all *buntus. HW-related issues may be solved by using a newer release of Ubuntu.